# Javascript finding indexOf select option

Tags: javascript

So this is what I managed to do, use a text box to add strings to my select.
How can I now use a second text box to write part of a string I created in the select with the first text box and find the indexOf the word I typed(indexOf need to appear underneath the second text box)?

Note: the simplest Javascript answer, please.

```
    function addString(){
        var addTwoSelect = document.getElementById("select");
        var write = document.createElement("option");
        write.text = document.getElementById("txt").value;
        addTwoSelect.add(write);        
    }


<input type="text" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" value="add string" onclick="addString()"/>
<select id="select"><option value="0">Choose a string</option></select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so just a second input box and compute the `indexOf`:

```
function addString(){
    var addTwoSelect = document.getElementById("select");
    var write = document.createElement("option");
    write.value = write.text = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    addTwoSelect.add(write);
}
function outputIndex() {
    var addTwoSelect = document.getElementById("select"),
        secondBox = document.getElementById("string"),
        out = document.getElementById("index");
    out.innerText = addTwoSelect.value.indexOf(secondBox.value);
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" value="add string" onclick="addString()"/>
<select id="select" onchange="outputIndex()"><option value="0">Choose a string</option></select>
<input type="text" id="string" oninput="outputIndex()"/>
<output id="index"></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `value` attributes of your `<option>`s!

```
var last = 0;
function addString(){
    var addTwoSelect = document.getElementById("select");
    var write = document.createElement("option");
    write.text = document.getElementById("txt").value;
    write.value = ++last;
    addTwoSelect.add(write);        
}
function outputIndex() {
    var addTwoSelect = document.getElementById("select"),
        out = document.getElementById("index");
    out.innerText = addTwoSelect.value;
}
```

```
<input type="text" id="txt"/>
<input type="button" value="add string" onclick="addString()"/>
<select id="select" onchange="outputIndex()"><option value="0">Choose a string</option></select>
<output id="index"></output>
```

Comment: Thank you but it wasn't what I meant. After adding a few strings, each with more than one word, what I want is to select one of the strings I added to the select as an option, write in a second text box (one to add string, the other to find indexOf) part of the added string and find the indexOf the word I entered in the string it belongs to.